# error says my activity class is not complete but it is angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

So I'm getting this error

```
ERROR in src/app/main/select-activity-typ
e/select-activity-type.component.ts(87,11
): error TS2322: Type '{ activity: any; h
eader: string; activities: ({ activityNam
e: string; available: false; link: str...
' is not assignable to type 'ActivitySele
ction'.                                  
Property 'activityName' is missing in t
ype '{ activity: any; header: string; act
ivities: ({ activityName: string; availab
le: false; link: str...'.                
src/app/main/select-activity-type/select-
activity-type.component.ts(115,9): error 
TS2322: Type '{ activity: any; header: st
ring; activities: ({ activityName: string
; available: false; link: str...' is not 
assignable to type 'ActivitySelection'.  
Property 'activityName' is missing in t
ype '{ activity: any; header: string; act
ivities: ({ activityName: string; availab
le: false; link: str...'.                
src/app/main/select-activity-type/select-
activity-type.component.ts(143,9): error 
TS2322: Type '{ activity: string; header:
string; activities: ({ activityName: str
ing; available: false; link: ...' is not 
assignable to type 'ActivitySelection'.  
Property 'activityName' is missing in t
ype '{ activity: string; header: string; 
activities: ({ activityName: string; avai
lable: false; link: ...'.                
src/app/main/select-activity-type/select-
activity-type.component.ts(171,9): error 
TS2322: Type '{ activity: string; header:
string; activities: ({ activityName: str
ing; available: false; link: ...' is not 
assignable to type 'ActivitySelection'.  
Property 'activityName' is missing in t
ype '{ activity: string; header: string; 
activities: ({ activityName: string; avai
lable: false; link: ...'.
```

when I run ng serve, now from the looks of it, its having some issue with the activitySelection

in my component.ts

```
activity = {
        activity: Something,
        activityName: 'something',
        activityTypeName: 'somethingsomething',
        header: 'SOMETHING',
        activities: [
          {
            activityName: 'Pre-Activity',
            available: false,
            link: ''
          },
          {
            activityName: 'Today',
            available: true,
            link: '/app/main/etc'
          }
        ]
    };

   ...
```

and this is my interface

```
  export interface ActivitySelection {
   activity: string;
   activityName: string;
   activityTypeName: string;
   header: string;
   activities:
     {
       activityName: string;
       available: boolean;
       link: string;
     }[];
 }
```

I'm not sure what the issue is? I have implemented the interface correcty??

And help would be appreciated!

Comment: `activity: Something` is a string or a class ?

Comment: There all strings I just forgot to add the quotes for the example

Comment: It doesn't seem there is an issue in your code. Could you reproduce it in a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.io ?

Comment: On what line of the code snippet is the error reported?  Perhaps you have other `ActivitySelection` objects in the file that are missing the `activityName` field?